# How to group the rows and add a number

Tags: excel

I need sequential number on this group of items of students in Excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEXPy.jpg)

Comment: could you pls further elaborate the requirement, what kind of sequential number is required

Comment: Use COUNTIF function for it

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to do but i think you can use COUNTIF formula:
In example if you want calculate Number 1  Adam students:

=COUNTIFS(A:A;"Adam";B:B;"1")

Answer (score 0):

Enter the formula in cell `B2` and drag down to get the numbers in sequence,

```
=IF(A1=A2,B1,MAX($B$1:$B1)+1)
```

[image]

Note:- Your student names in column A has to be sorted order as in image, or this formula would'nt work